# Сериализация и Десериализация  C#

Tags: c#, .net

Имеется некий класс, который необходимо сериализовать, т.е. получить массив байт в переменную. Какими способами это можно сделать?, Пробовал написать с помощью интерфейса ISerializable. Есть ли другие хорошие способы?

Например класс:

```
class cTestMessageClass
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    private Int64 D { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Почему именно "массив байт"? Расскажите, для чего именно вам нужна сериализация, без контекста правильный ответ невозможен.

Comment: @VladD Реализовал общение программ через WVF (Windows Communication Foundation). Но ему, для передачи класса, необходимо заранее знать что передаваться будет, какой тип и т.д. С известными классами все в порядке, но мне надо передать неизвестный класс (как object). Т.е. этот объект может преобразовать сама программа, и библиотека передачи ничего о нем не знает. Поэтому решил преобразовывать класс в массив байт, его передавать, а на той стороне обратно перевести в класс.

Comment: @IVsevolod: хм, почему тогда не XML-сериализация?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь встроенной сериализацией. Для этого достаточно дать классу атрибут `Serializable`:

```
[Serializable]
class TestMessage
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public double B { get; set; }
    public string C { get; set; }
    private Int64 D { get; set; }
}
```

Если вам и правда нужна бинарная сериализация (означающая потенциальные проблемы при работе в гетерогенной системе), используйте `BinaryFormatter`:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TestMessage tm1 = ...;
        var stream = Save(tm1);
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        var tm2 = Load(stream);
    }

    static Stream Save(TestMessage tm)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var stream = new MemoryStream();
        formatter.Serialize(stream, tm);
        return stream;
    }

    static TestMessage Load(Stream s)
    {
        var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
        var tm = (TestMessage)formatter.Deserialize(s);
        return tm;
    }
}
```

В качестве альтернативы можно использовать XML-сериализацию, но учтите, что она "из коробки" игнорирует приватные свойства, так что нужно будет либо имплементировать `ISerializable`/`IXmlSerializable`, либо использовать `DataContractSerializer` вместо `XmlSerializer`.

Comment: спасибо :) со вторым методом удалось получить массив байт, передать его, и обратно перевести в класс :) Думаю лучших идей никто не предложит. А XML сериализацию попробую сделать )

Comment: @IVsevolod: Пожалуйста! Удачи!

Answer (score 3):

Я использовал JSON.NET для сериализации и остался им очень доволен!
ваш пример будет выглядеть в нем вот так:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Converters;

[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]
[JsonConverter(typeof(cTestMessageClassConverter ))]
class cTestMessageClass
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public int A { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public double B { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    public string C { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    private Int64 D { get; set; }
}

// Конвертер JSON
public class cTestMessageClassConverter : CustomCreationConverter<cTestMessageClass>
{
    public override cTestMessageClass Create(Type objectType)
    {
        return new cTestMessageClass();
    }
}
```

Сериализация:
string s = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(testMessage);

//десериализация
cTestMessageClass cd = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<cTestMessageClass >(z);

Comment: спасибо ) завтра тоже попробую )

Answer (score 2):

Сериализуйте в [xml](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx).

Comment: Или в json.

Answer (score 1):

Если нужна быстрая сериализация, то придется отказаться от штатной реализации.
В вашем случае это может выглядеть так:

```
interface ISupportsBinarySerialization
{
    void Serialize(out byte[] buffer);
    void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer);
    void Deserialize(byte[] buffer);
    void Deserialize(BinaryReader reader);
}

class TestMessageClass : ISupportsBinarySerialization
{
    public int A
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public double B
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public string C
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    private long D
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public void Serialize(out byte[] buffer)
    {
        var size = 0
               + sizeof(int)
               + sizeof(double)
               + sizeof(int) + sizeof(char)*C.Length
               + sizeof(long);

        buffer = new byte[size];

        var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
        Serialize(writer);
        writer.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();
    }

    public void Serialize(BinaryWriter writer)
    {
        writer.Write(A);

        writer.Write(B);

        var str = Encoding.Unicode.GetBytes(C);
        writer.Write(str.Length);
        writer.Write(str);

        writer.Write(D);
    }

    public void Deserialize(byte[] buffer)
    {
        var stream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
        var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.Unicode);
        Deserialize(reader);
        reader.Dispose();
        stream.Dispose();
    }

    public void Deserialize(BinaryReader reader)
    {
        A = reader.ReadInt32();

        B = reader.ReadDouble();

        var strLen = reader.ReadInt32();
        C = Encoding.Unicode.GetString(reader.ReadBytes(strLen));

        D = reader.ReadInt64();
    }
}
```

Comment: Появляется проблема, если структура класса меняется, или становится громоздкой. Но все равно спасибо )

Comment: @IVsevolod, это плата за скорость. Либо быстро, либо удобно. Рефлекшн в дотнете пока очень тормозной, к сожалению.

Answer (score 0):

Когда я пробовал сериализацию в .net, возникали накладки с различной версией сборок и еще чем то, т.е. это был не просто гибкий набор байт.

Как хороший вариант могу предложить делать сериализацию **вручную**, в байтах или xml:

```
long V = 42;
//байты:
byte[] = BitConverter.GetBytes(V);
//xml:
xdoc.AddNode(string.Format("<param type='{0}'>{1}</param>",V,V.GetType()));
```

Конечно, необходима еще и структура.

Ну и соответственно смотря для каких целей приложение.

Comment: по поводу ручного варианта, лучше сразу в последовательность байтов записывать, чем хранить в виде xml.

Comment: если, конечно, не нужен удобочитаемый вид, то да.