# .net core c# строковая версия массива в массив

Tags: php, c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

уважаемые форумчане!
Хочу написать для контрольной работы - магазинчик. Уже спарсил на php один сайт, поместил информацию в mysql (некоторые данные шли массивом, потому я их функцией serialize(some_array) поместил в базу, вышла строковая версия массива). Начав работать с c# - столкнулся с необходимостью расшифровать строковую версию массива в массив, для того, что бы можно было потом массив с размерами правильно всунуть в сайт. На данном этапе я просто беру данные из базы, и вот что выводит **( Тег Размер(строковая версия массива)).**

```
   Футболка a:1:{i:0;s:1:"M";}
   Футболка a:3:{i:0;s:1:"L";i:1;s:2:"XL";i:2;s:1:"M";}
   Футболка a:3:{i:0;s:1:"S";i:1;s:1:"M";i:2;s:2:"XL";}
   Футболка a:1:{i:0;s:1:"M";}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне превратить это в массив, то есть - какая альтернатива есть в C# функции unserialize(some_string_array) из php ?

Заранее благодарю !)

Comment: Раз для контрольной: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206262/Сериализация-и-Десериализация-c

Comment: Не забудьте только функции переименовать, а то спалят :D

Comment: Или тут посмотрите https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-suitable-objec

Comment: А что это за формат данных такой? Это не Json, не Xml, а не понятно что. Зачем создавать себе сложности? Формировать данные в формат не пойми чего, а потом биться над тем, чтоб из этого не пойми чего получить что-то удобоваримое? Ну, есть в C# у строки метод `Split()`, можете разбить строку в массив используя разделитель `:`, а потом работать с этим массивом...

Comment: Переделайте хранение массива. Избавьтесь от сериализации, замените на JSON или XML. Сериализация - вещь сугубо специфичная в PHP. Это велосипед на костылях и использовать его имеет смысл только если он не выходит за рамки PHP

Comment: есть реализации unserialize https://gist.github.com/xiangwan/1225981  и https://github.com/NetworksAreMadeOfString/L4DStats/tree/master/Windows/PHPSerializationLibrary и PHPSerializationLibrary (у меня есть исходники, но где брал не найду)

Answer (score 0):

PHP не знаю, странный какой-то формат строки, но может это поможет: https://gordon-breuer.de/unknown/2011/05/04/php-un-serialize-with-c.html

Answer (score 0):

Можно вот тут посмотреть https://sourceforge.net/projects/csphpserial
Вроде бы некоторые товарищи как раз там и нашли решение проблемы.
Например https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1914585/how-to-unserialize-php-serialized-array-variable-class-and-return-suitable-objec