# Сериализация и десериализация не работают

Tags: c#, сериализация

Мне нужно чтобы  записывалась матрица в  файл  и считывалась  с него.
Я написал код,  но мне выдает ошибку  что  не может записать в файл. Нужна ваша помощь

```
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();

        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("matrix.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
        {
            formatter.Serialize(fs, matplus);

            Console.WriteLine("Объект сериализован");
        }

        //десериализация
        using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("matrix.dat", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
        {
            Matrix deserilizeMatrix = (Matrix)formatter.Deserialize(fs);
            Console.WriteLine("Ета матрица?");
        }
```

Comment: "выдает ошибку что не может записать в файл" - этими словами?

Comment: Я-то ответ дал, но на будущее имей ввиду "не работают" -- это не вопрос. Пиши всю возможную информацию в максимально сжатом виде.

Comment: @Andrew выдает  такую ошибку: System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 'Type 'Task1.Matrix' in Assembly 'MatrixAndPolynom, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.'

Comment: Файл создается,  но  он  пустой

Comment: @VovaMakarovych а теперь читай ошибку внимательно, а именно "is not marked as serializable" и читай мой ответ -- самый первый блок кода.

Comment: @Andrew спасибо. я это [Serializable] в середине класу делал.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сериализация и Десериализация  C#](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/206262/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%94%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-c)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

к классу который будем сериализовать добавляем

```
[Serializable]//вот эта!
public class SomeItem
{}
```

Враппер на сериализацию:

```
public static class Serializator
{
    private static BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter();

    public static void Serialize(string pathOrFileName, object objToSerialise)
    {
        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            try 
            {
                _bin.Serialize(stream, objToSerialise);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to serialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }
    }

    public static T Deserialize<T>(string pathOrFileName) 
    {
        T items;

        using (Stream stream = File.Open(pathOrFileName, FileMode.Open))
        {
            try 
            {
                items = (T) _bin.Deserialize(stream);
            }
            catch (SerializationException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Failed to deserialize. Reason: " + e.Message);
                throw;
            }
        }

        return items;
    }
}
```

ну и, собственно, сам пример использования:

```
List<SomeItem> itemsCollected;//list with some data

Serializator.Serialize("data.dat", itemsCollected);

var a = Serializator.Deserialize<List<SomeItem>>("data.dat");
// обрати внимание что при десериализации ты должен задать вместо 
// List<SomeItem> нужный формат данных
```

В случае ошибки будет выдавать в консоль сообщение о исключении сериализации.

Comment: как у этой конструкции `private static BinaryFormatter _bin = new BinaryFormatter();` с потокобезопасностью? Мне кажется, лучше его просто каждый раз создавать в нужных методах, чем держать один инстанс на всё.

Comment: Если чесно, то понятия не имею - как-то не понадобилось ни разу пользоваться в разных потоках. Но, наверное, и вправду лучше убрать статичность и делать все через инстансы.