# Как сделать загрузку элементов формы (windows forms) без задержки?

Tags: c#

У меня есть программа написанная на *windows forms* , которая при запуске грузит данные из *.txt файла (*объем файла постепенно увеличивается*) и отображает их после загрузки в таблице *dataGriedView*.

Так вот, проблема в том, что данные при запуске формы отображаются с задержкой небольшой. Во время запуска программы, форма прогружается сначала пустая, а остальное появляется с небольшой задержкой.

**Как сделать это более красивее? Как показать форму именно тогда, когда все данные будут загружены и готовы к показу и без задержки?**

Comment: Что не даёт переместить данные в БД?

Comment: @Streletz, в данном случае это пока не имеет значение. Я работаю с текстовыми файлами и меня это устраивает. 

Comment: Можно спрятать форму пока данные грузятся. Только, что подумает пользователь, когда он вроде запустил программу, а формы долго нет? Если только заставку сделать с прогрессбаром...

Comment: @Streletz, заставку сделать можно. Беда в том, что я не понимаю как сделать отображение данных без задержки именно тогда, когда они готовы. Пошел гуглить. 

Comment: Открывайте Program.cs и делайте загрузку данных оттуда, перед показом окна

Comment: Оптимизируйте подгрузку данных (например можно грузить ен сразу все,а по 10)...если придусмотрена многократная загрузка одних и тех-же данных, то кешируйте

Comment: Я как пользователь предпочёл бы, чтобы окно приложение появилось сразу, а не потом. Так я сразу вижу, что оно не зависло, а работает. А данные пусть подгрузятся потом. Достаточно надписи "Loading..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Любой из этих вариантов должен решить твою проблему:

- Сделай заставку и показывай ее до момента пока не прогрузятся данные, а потом уже показывай вторую форму с самими данными.

  в program.cs подгружаешь данные в асинхронном методе. Обновляя при этом переменную с ходом загрузки. Как только загрузка достигнет 100% закрываем форму-заставку и открываем MainForm.
- Перемести данные в место с которого они будут грузится быстрее. Например в БД. Или сериализованный файл ( можно подсмотреть код вот здесь [Сериализация и десериализация не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941645/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82/941648#941648) ) -- бинарные файлы обрабатываются быстрее текста.
- Не грузи ВСЕ данные. Грузи только то что прям сейчас нужно отображать -- т.е. сделай его виртуальным. И то грузи эти данные в левый посредник, а потом отрисовывай данные из этого посредника в DataGridView через DataSource.

  Переключи DGV в виртуал моуд через блок пропертей в вижуал студио, а потом напиши реализацию:

  ```
  private void dataGridView1_CellValueNeeded(
  ```

  собственно, в интернете туториалов с примерами кода просто нереально много в т.ч. есть в [документации мелкософта](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/controls/implementing-virtual-mode-wf-datagridview-control). Иначе -- гугли "datagridview virtual example".

Comment: А можно примеры кода, для каждого случая?

Comment: кажется нужно выполнить все 3 варианта

Comment: Поддерживаю @Monomax, желательно бы код с маленьким примером работы для 2 и 3 пункта . Если не сложно...

Comment: @StarStrit Просто расписал детальнее. Пробуй любой из путей, не получится -- создавай новый вопрос который будет затравлен самой попыткой написать хоть что-то и будут конкретные ответы с кодом. :)

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц все 3 варианта исполнять безсмысленно в принципе. Максимум 1+2 или 2+3. И то на маленькой программе, даже, это безсмысленно и будет достаточно лишь 1го из них. А у автора вопроса программа именно такая.

Comment: _бинарные файлы обрабатываются быстрее текста_ - не всегда. Я бы вообще убрал этот пункт из ответа. Имхо.

Comment: Сплэш-скрин и виртуализация грида - это действенные варианты.

Answer (score 0):

Одним из вариантов решения данной проблемы может выступать сериализация.
Ниже приведен один из примеров бинарной сериализации при помощи **BinaryFormatter**, который находится в пространстве имен **System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.** Также сериализуемый класс должен быть помечен атрибутом **[Serializable].** Еще примеры бинарной сериализации можно найти: [здесь](https://metanit.com/sharp/tutorial/6.2.php) и [здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8).

```
         //Сериализация
        BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter(); // создаем объект BinaryFormatter

        string fileName = Test.Name.Trim(System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()).TrimEnd((System.IO.Path.GetInvalidFileNameChars()));

        string path = $"{Environment.CurrentDirectory}" + "\\Tests\\" + $"{fileName}.dat"; //Собираемый полный путь до файла куда будем сериализовать 
        try
        {
            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) // создаем объект FileStream для записи в файл.
            {
                formatter.Serialize(fs, Test); //Вызываем у formatter метод Serialize, который принимает объект FileStram и сериализуемый объект
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            return;
        }

    //Десериализация
    OpenFileDialog openFileDialog = new OpenFileDialog(); // в данной программе использовался OoenFileDialog для поиска файлов для десериализации.
        openFileDialog.Filter = "(*.dat)|*.dat";
        openFileDialog.InitialDirectory = testsDirectory.FullName;

        if (openFileDialog.ShowDialog() == true)
        {
            BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            Test test;
            try
            {
                using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(openFileDialog.FileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate)) //Здесь FileStream инициализируется путем полученным из OpenFileDialog. Можно использовать константный путь к файлу.
                {
                    test = (Test)formatter.Deserialize(fs); //Вызываем функцию Deserialize, которая принимает FileStream и возвращает object. Приводим к типу который был сериализован.
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return;
            }
```

Comment: Приведите пояснения к Вашему ответу

Comment: @SergeyNudnov в виде комментариев достаточно?

Comment: Ваш ответ, возможно, хорош, но он не понятен без чтения кода. Опишите перед кодом, своими словами, что Вы предлагаете. Комментарии в коде тоже хорошо, но это немного другое...

Comment: @SergeyNudnov а такой вариант?

Comment: Да не является это решением проблемы. Тем более бинарная сериализация зачастую более медленная и громоздкая, чем текстовая.

Comment: Так лучше - в плане оформления. Добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow!

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov конечно, текстовая сериализация быстрее бинарной, но мы не видим код задающего вопрос человека. Может быть так, что в данном случае даже бинарная сериализация будет быстрее той, которая есть там. Может быть там есть что оптимизировать.