# Как правильно считывать бинарный файл

Tags: c#, filestream, binary-file

У меня есть коллекция Book, в которой содержаться список книг. Я создаю бинарный файл и записываю в него эти данные. С записью проблем нет, файл создается и содержит все введенные мною данные. Вопрос, а как правильно считывать эти данные из бинарного файла, что бы я потом мог их просмотреть?

```
// Если файла не существует, то создаем
if (!File.Exists(_path + "\\Books.bin"))
{
    _books.Add(new Books
    {
        BookName = "Книга 1",
        Author = "Автор 1",
        PageCount = 200,
        Year = 2000
    });

    _books.Add(new Books
    {
        BookName = "Книга 2",
        Author = "Автор 2",
        PageCount = 400,
        Year = 2010
    });

    _books.Add(new Books
    {
        BookName = "Книга 3",
        Author = "Автор 3",
        PageCount = 820,
        Year = 2005
    });

    using (var fileStream = new FileStream(_path + "\\Books.bin", FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (BinaryWriter writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
        {
            foreach (var book in _books)
            {
                writer.Write(book.BookName);
                writer.Write(book.Author);
                writer.Write(book.PageCount);
                writer.Write(book.Year);
            }
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}

// Читаем файл
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(_path + "\\Books.bin", FileMode.Open)))
{

}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Сериализация и десериализация не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941645/%d0%a1%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8-%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В ответе [@Rekssel](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1023430/217579) чтение прекращается с помощью проверки `PeekChar()`. Один из двух общепринятых способов: читаем, пока не встретим маркер конца.

Другой способ: в начале записываем длину данных. При чтении, соответственно, сперва считываем эту длину.

```
// Запись
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Create))
using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(fileStream))
{
    writer.Write(_books.Count);

    foreach (var book in _books)
    {
        writer.Write(book.BookName);
        writer.Write(book.Author);
        writer.Write(book.PageCount);
        writer.Write(book.Year);
    }
}

// Чтение
using (var fileStream = new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(fileStream))
{
    int count = reader.ReadInt32();
    _books = new List<Books>(count);

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
    {
        _books.Add(new Books
        {
            BookName = reader.ReadString(),
            Author = reader.ReadString(),
            PageCount = reader.ReadInt32(),
            Year = reader.ReadInt32()
        });
    }
}
```

Недостаток этого способа в том, что при записи нужно знать длину данных, а это не всегда известно, допустим, у нас источник данных `IEnumerable` или `IQueryable`.

Достоинство этого способа в том, что при чтении можно сразу выделить буфер нужной длины. При этом не будет лишних переаллокаций в дальнейшем.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [BinaryFormatter](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.formatters.binary.binaryformatter?view=netframework-4.8).

Например:

Для записи:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("books.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    formatter.Serialize(fs, "ваш_объект");
}
```

Для считывания:

```
BinaryFormatter formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("books.bin", FileMode.OpenOrCreate))
{
    "тип_вашего_объекта" obj = ("тип_вашего_объекта")formatter.Deserialize(fs);
}
```

Comment: этот метод проще и "вкуснее для восприятия"

Answer (score 2):

Предположу, что так:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
    {
        _books.Add(new Books
        {
            BookName = reader.ReadString(),
            Author = reader.ReadString(),
            PageCount = reader.ReadInt32(),
            Year = reader.ReadInt32()
        });
    }
}
```

Или так:

```
using (BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(File.Open(path, FileMode.Open)))
{
    while (reader.PeekChar() > -1)
    {
        Books book = new Books();            
        book.BookName = reader.ReadString();
        book.Author = reader.ReadString();
        book.PageCount = reader.ReadInt32();
        book.Year = reader.ReadInt32();
        _books.Add(book);
    }
}
```

Comment: Важен порядок считывания. Он должен быть в том же порядке, что и запись.