# CefSharp - как установить куки из файла?

Tags: c#, winforms, cookie, cefsharp

Использую Хром браузер. Получены куки через `Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().VisitAllCookies(visitor);` и записаны в файл.

После считывания записанных данных пробую установить через `Cef.GetGlobalCookieManager().SetCookieAsync` или `browser.GetCookieManager().SetCookieAsync()` и ничего не получается.

Установка такого плана:

```
        await Cef.UIThreadTaskFactory.StartNew(delegate
        {
            List<Cookie> cookies = File.ReadLines(@"C:\cookies").Select(x => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Cookie>(x)).ToList();

            foreach (Cookie cookie in cookies)
                browser.GetCookieManager().SetCookieAsync(cookie.Domain, cookie);
        });
```

Как поступить?

Comment: _Как поступить?_ - добавить нерабочий код в вопрос. Как вы записываете в файл, и как читаете и пытаетесь установить.

Comment: Добавил. Может есть работающее решение?

Comment: А отладку пробовали? Может у вас куки из фала не считываются.

Comment: Читаются, все в этом плане ок. Без брекпоинтов и проверок не работаю, поэтому в плане получения данных да, получаются как надо, а вот после сета они null, то есть не хотят ставится и все (как и путь к кэшу).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

задавать куки вручную в CefSharp можно вот так:

```
Cef.SetCookie("192.168.1.6/mywebsite", "/", "MyCookie", "true", new DateTime(2100, 1, 1));
```

Я не в курсе есть ли возможность сериализации кук напрямую, но наверняка есть возможность чтения данных записаных в куки.

Соответственно если нет возможности прямой сериализации - возьми список кук из CefSharp и скопируй в свою собственную реализацию а потом сериализируй или бинарно (например так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/941648/186752 ) или в XML (сам поищи)

А потом в необходимый момент трешь все куки CefSharp и проходишься циклом по десериализованным добавляя через код поданый выше. И перезагружаешь страницу.

Answer (score 1):

в цефШарп не нужно вручную куки сохранять и загружать.

Самый простой способ - это задать в настройках путь для кеша. Куки будут подтягиватся автоматически с этого кеша. Для этого тебя интересует `CefSettings.CachePath`

То есть добавить на старте программы до инициализации цеф-а что-то такое:

```
CefSharp.CefSettings settings = new CefSharp.CefSettings();

settings.CachePath = @"D:\CEF_Cache"; 

CefSharp.Cef.Initialize(settings);
```

Этого достаточно и никакой дополнительный код не нужен.

Comment: По поводу "в цефШарп не нужно вручную куки сохранять и загружать". Суть вопроса в том, чтобы загружать вручную по требованию. Зачем? Так надо, например, когда перелогиррование пользователя с нужными куками или они импортируются из определенного места, скажем, бд и все "на лету". Поэтому и был задан в те далекие времена подобный вопрос, поэтому в данном случае ответ вообще не подходит и не является ответом на поставленный вопрос.

Comment: дал второй ответ. Этот не удаляю ибо он более универсальный и подойдет более широкому спектру людей.