# как сделать так, чтобы CefSharp не удалял данные после закрытия формы (не приходилось вписывать данные для входа снова)?

Tags: c#, winforms, cefsharp

после перезапуска форма снова просит данные для входа на сайт, такого быть не должно.

Comment: Насколько я помню, то так делает хэдлесс хром, и ему надо принудительно подгружать профиль юзера каждый раз.

Answer (score 0):

Есть такое понятие как Cookie - это данные с сайтов которые хранят в том числе и сессии на сайтах.

Твоя задача или сохранять и подгружать куки вручную при запуске твоей программы или же использовать профили cefSharp-a.

В первую очередь смотри документацию самой библиотеки в сторону `CefSettings.cache_path` и `--cache-path` - например через них должно быть возможно(теоретически) использовать, даже, кеш хрома(включающий в себя в том числе куки) т.к. движок тот же.

ответ раз: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1268355/186752

ответ-костыль два: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1268769/186752